# Protractor - right clicking within chrome shows wrong menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, protractor

When manually testing the context menu within Chrome the results are as expected:[image: expected right click menu]

But when protractor attempts to mimic the same situation, the browser's menu appears:[image: unexpected right click menu]

The code that I am using to trigger the menu is as follows:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id(word2Id))).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Can anyone suggest an approach to fixing this issue, or a solution? As I am currently stumped.

EDIT: adding a sleep before and after the mouse move makes the test sometimes work. I changed the sleeps to 10 seconds and there wasn't an improvement. I have added a test below (some of the code is weird as I have removed the method calls).

```
var module = testData.modules[3];
loginPage.login(process.env.TDC_TEST_USER, process.env.TDC_TEST_PASS);

var url = resourcePage.buildModuleResourceUrl(module._id, module.resources[1], "title");
url = TestConfig.BASE_URL + "/test/iframe?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&width=991px&height=1000px";
browser.driver.get(url);

// load the module/resource in a iframe to simulate a small screen
browser.switchTo().frame(browser.driver.findElement(by.id("embeddedPlayerFrame")));
expect(element(by.id("btnClassCommentsLeftPanel")).getAttribute("class")).toContain("active");
expect(element(by.id("btnPersonalCommentsLeftPanel")).getAttribute("class")).not.toContain("active");

var type = "personal";
var startWordIndex = 11; 

var pagedMenuBtn = type === "class" ? "pagedMenuClassComment" : "pagedMenuPersonalNote";
var saveBtnTxt = type === "class" ? "Comment" : "Create Note";
var word1Id = "ocr_word_0_" + startWordIndex;
var word2Id = "ocr_word_0_" + (startWordIndex + 1); 
var word3Id = "ocr_word_0_" + (startWordIndex + 2); 

expect(element(by.id(word1Id)).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(element(by.id(word2Id)).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(element(by.id(word3Id)).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

browser.actions()
    .mouseDown(element(by.id(word1Id)))
    .mouseMove(element(by.id(word1Id)))
    .mouseMove(element(by.id(word2Id)))
    .mouseMove(element(by.id(word3Id)))
    .mouseUp(element(by.id(word3Id)))
    .perform();

browser.sleep(1000);
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id(word2Id))).perform();
browser.sleep(100);

// create a new class comment annotation by right clicking
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

EDIT: this works perfectly in Firefox, but not chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try to use browser.sleep('somemilliseconds') before mouse actions or show your full code here.

Comment: updated the description above. Adding sleeps slightly increases the reliability, but not by much.